# Total spin Operator on a state that is not an eigenstate

Tags: quantum-spin

This question is inspired from case $(iii)$ of part $A$ of question $7.7$ of Modern Quantum Mechanics by Sakurai.

Say we have a system of three spin $1$ bosons with symmetric space functions. We then know that the spin states must be symmetric under permutation. The state consisting of all bosons occupying different spin states can then be shown to not be an eigenstate of the total spin operator:

$$\mathbf{S}^2=\mathbf{S}_1^2+\mathbf{S}_2^2+\mathbf{S}_3^2+2(\mathbf{S}_1\cdot\mathbf{S}_1+\mathbf{S}_1\cdot\mathbf{S}_3+\mathbf{S}_2\cdot\mathbf{S}_3)$$

where we have labeled the bosons $1,2,3$.

My question is this, how do we then define the total spin of a state which is not an eigenstate of the total spin operator? If it were we would simply set is eigenvalue $\lambda$ equal to $s(s+1)$, but I am unclear how to do so in this case.

Comment: How do you normally define the total value of some quantity for which a state is not an eigenstate? Like total energy for a superposition of two energy eigenstates?

Comment: @QuantumMechanic with an expectation value, but that doesn't make a tone of sense here if we want to get an $s$ such that $s(s+1)\hbar^2$ is equal to the expectation value.

Comment: Isn't that the point? You can't define some quantity for a state that isn't an eigenstate of that operator!

Comment: "The state consisting of all bosons occupying different spin states can then be shown to not be an eigenstate of the total spin operator". False: all three states you constructed have spin 3, and eigenvalue 12 for **S** $^2$. Start with i) and note the lowering operator commutes with **S** $^2$. Apply it twice.